# Collection is empty when a route calls it, but if I go away and come back, the collection holds what it is supposed to

Tags: django, backbone.js, backbone-views, tastypie, backbone-routing

The code works every-time EXCEPT for when the router is first called with page load. The, the collection is created, but it's not populated with the `notes.fetch();`. I've been looking all over, and I can't see why this is happening.

For example, when I go to the URL to load this page, everything but what is in the collection loads. When I go to `#blank/' and then go "Back" to the`list` view, the collection AND the models load as they are supposed to. SO how do I get the collection to load once the page loads?

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {

    // Note: The model and collection are extended from TastypieModel and TastypieCollection
    // to handle the parsing and URLs

    window.Note = TastypieModel.extend({});

    window.Notes = TastypieCollection.extend({
        model: Note,
        url: NOTES_API_URL
    });

    window.notes = new Notes();

    window.NoteView = Backbone.View.extend({

        className: "panel panel-default note",
        template: _.template($('#notes-item').html()),
        events: {
            'click .note .edit': 'editNoteToggle',
            'click .note .edit-note': 'doEdit'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },
        editNoteToggle: function() {
            console.log("I've toggled the edit box");
        },
        doEdit: function() {
            console.log('This will edit the note');
        }
    });

    window.NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#app",
        template: _.template($('#notes-item-list').html()),
        events: {
            'click #add-note': 'addNote'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addNote');
            this.collection.bind('change', this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            console.log('before the loop');
            console.log(this.collection.toJSON()); //<- Empty when it first loads, then contains the models when I visit another page and come "back" to this page
            this.collection.each(function(note){
                var view = new NoteView({ model: note });
                $('#notes-list').append(view.render().el);
            });
            console.log('done');
            $('#add-note-toggle').on('click', this, function() {
                $('#note-add-form').toggle();
            });
            return this;
        },
        addNote: function() {
            console.log('The add note was clicked');
        }
    });

    window.NotesRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'list',
            'blank/': 'blank'
        },
        initialize: function() {
            // starts by assigning the collection to a variable so that it can load the collection
            this.notesView = new NoteListView({
                collection: notes
            });
            notes.fetch();
        },
        list: function () {
            $('#app').empty();
            $('#app').append(this.notesView.render().el);
        },
        blank: function() {
            $('#app').empty();
            $('#app').text('Another view');
        }
    });

    window.notesRouter = new NotesRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your listening to the wrong collection event. Try using

```
window.NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
    }
    // ...
});
window.NotesRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    // ...
    initialize: function() {
        notes.fetch({reset: true});
    }
    // ...
});
```

Right now you are firing off an async `collection.fetch()`, which will eventually load the data. Problem is, once that data is loaded into the collection, it won't fire a `change` event, just a bunch of `add`s. When you go to the blank page and back, you're data has arrived by the second `render` call and displays properly.

If you modify your `fetch()` to throw a `reset` event and then listen for that, you'll have a freshly rendered NoteList once the data comes in without the need to go to the blank page.

Comment: Just as a quick follow up, why would Backbone.js have turned that off then in 1.1? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're doing things much the same as I would. But, fetch will only fire `change` events when a model with the same id already exists in the collection and a property is changed.